# Selecting cli menu options from my bash script

Tags: bash

I'm running a bash script but the process freezes when it hit a menu where it have to make a selection
I understand that for YES ican use -y in my commands, but in the case where:

1. I need to select/enter a number from an options list
2. Enter a name or an email

How can I do that?

Weird enough that most of the search results return how to create a menu using bash, but not how to make a script enter selections/values.

Comment: Without the script source we hardly can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pipe a text with the answers to the command:

```
printf "bot\nn\nJava" | ./questions.sh
```

Or use `expect` like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
spawn ../4/questions.sh

expect "Your name: "
send -- "expect\n"

expect "Are you human?\r
y/n: "
send -- "n\r"

expect "What is your favorite programming language?\r
Your answer: "
send -- "Java\r"

expect eof
```

more info here
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-interactive-prompts

Comment: Thank you @ttsakpc , what about selections in screens like this one? https://images.app.goo.gl/uwRDDpBPkN3JxeGk8

Comment: I believe that it should also work with `expect`. If not you can try `empty-expect` as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66199156/how-can-i-make-a-bash-inputmenu-dialog-start-with-rename-automatically-clicked